# How do I resolve this Angular error in a VS 2022 solution involving Standalone Angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2022

I tried out [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022) and followed every step exactly as given. However, I am getting an error when I attempt to execute the application:

[image]

What do I need to do to fix this? I get a similar error when trying the same steps with standalone TypeScript template project in VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by uninstalling the webpack and reinstalling it freshly. Thereafter, it worked fine. Am sharing this in case someone else encountered the same issue and maybe this solution can help them.

```
npm uninstall -g webpack

npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
```